# octave/ gnuplot - Plot RGB pixel intensities

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am trying to read an input image using octave and plot its RGB values as a 3 dimension plot.

I am reading image using

```
im = imread('image')
```

How can I plot this?

Also, is it possible to plot a histogram of all the 3 layers?

Thanks

Comment: The [Octave API doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html) says your **im** variable will be an MxNx3 matrix when you load a color image, so you should already have your "image data" as RGB channels. What do you want to plot, exactly?

Comment: Hi Sven, I would either like to plot my RGB channels as a 3D plot. 1 channel per dimension.

Or separate histograms per channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, the [Octave API doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html) gives you an MxNx3 matrix data set of your image.

The R/G/B channels are the last dimensions of your **im** matrix. **hist** needs 1d input, so we'll need to **reshape** it:

```
hist(reshape(im(:,:,1),1,[])) # red
hist(reshape(im(:,:,2),1,[])) # green
hist(reshape(im(:,:,3),1,[])) # blue
```

About the 3D plot: do you mean a [3D scatter plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot)? Then Octave's **scatter3** might help you.

Comment: Since these are images, it's better to use `imhist`, there's no need to `reshape`. But the difficulty is in having the three histograms in the same figure.